# Why does my button trigger PHP when I'm pressing the button?

Tags: php, html

I have created a PHP script that allows users on my site to sign up for our newsletter by entering their email and pressing the submit button. Then, it will give the user a notification to say that they have successfully signed up for our newsletter, and I will get an email. However, when you load the page (https://papaya-os.000webhostapp.com/) it sends me the email saying that somebody signed up, but the submit button was never pressed, and it doesn't show a success notification. On top of that, when you try to use the form correctly it doesn't work. Here is my PHP:

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {

    if(!$_POST["email"]) {

        $error = 'Please Enter Your Email';

    }
    if ($error) {

        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in submitting the form: ' .$error. '</strong></div>';

    }

} else {
    if(mail("colin.vrugteman@hotmail.com", "Newsletter Sign Up", "Email: ".$_POST['email'])) {

        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. You have been signed up for our newsletter!</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

I tried running the PHP on the top, and then the bottom of my HTML code, but neither worked. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the form? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: By fixing the formatting/indenting, you should be able to see why.

Comment: It seems, if submit is not set it will send an email to some Colin at Hotmail. So that sounds correct from your description, if submit is not pressed you get an email.

Comment: If you get an answer that helps you, be sure to check the little checkmark button by the answer to signify that it is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have mistake in parenthesis

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {

        if(!$_POST["email"]) {

            $error = 'Please Enter Your Email';

        }
        if ($error) {

            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in submitting the form: ' .$error. '</strong></div>';



         } else {
            if(mail("colin.vrugteman@hotmail.com", "Newsletter Sign Up", "Email: ".$_POST['email'])) {

              $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. You have been signed up for our newsletter!</div>';
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: You're calling mail("colin.vrugteman@ho.. in an if statement, and your parentheses are setup in a way that this runs even when nothing was submitted.

Comment: @BojanBedrač calling `mail()` in an if-statement is legal, as it returns true or false. If the mail is sent, it returns true, therefore giving the "Thank You." output.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks, I wasn't trying to say that it's illegal to call a method inside an if statement. I was trying to point out, that `mail()` gets called when the if statement gets evaluated and due to the structure of parentheses this was getting called every time.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that was not the case in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
    //Here you should be checking if submit is set, or `empty()` is my preferred function. You could also use `isset()` but you would want to negate that, so it would be `!isset()`.
    if(empty($_POST["submit"])) {
        //If email is empty, set $error
        if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $error = 'Please Enter Your Email';
        }
        //if $error is not empty, set $result
        if (!empty($error)) {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in submitting the form: ' . $error . '</strong></div>';
        }
    //if $_POST["submit"] IS set, send email.
    } else {
        //if $_POST['submit'] is NOT empty, and IS set, send email.
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (mail("colin.vrugteman@hotmail.com", "Newsletter Sign Up", "Email: " . $_POST['email'])) {
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. You have been signed up for our newsletter!</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Try this code, and I added comments to explain what was happening.

---

I personally would have wrote it to be more dynamic with the error code.

Here is how I would have personally wrote the code. I'm not claiming this is better or worse, just how I would have done it. :)

```
<?php
    //if submit is empty there was an issue
    if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {

        //create an empty array to store errors
        $errors = array();

        //loop through each _POST element to see what you are missing. If any value is empty or not set, it will be added to the errors.
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            //skip key submit because we don't want that to appear in the errors, you could also add more you want to skip here.
            if ($key == "submit")
                continue;
            //If value is empty/not set, add it to the error array.
            if (empty($value)) {
                array_push($errors, "Please provide " . ((in_array($key[0], $vocals)) ? "an" : "a") . " {$key}");
            }
        }
        //check if $errors has any contents
        if (!empty($errors)) {

            //create $results filled with the dynamic errors from above. If there is only 1 error, properly format the sentence.
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There '.((count($errors)==1)? "was an error" : "were errors" ).' while submitting the form: ';
            foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                $result .= "{$value}";
                if ($key != count($errors) - 1) {
                    $result .= ", ";
                }
            }
            $result .= '</strong></div>';
        }
    } else {
        //if if $_POST['submit'] is not empty and IS set, send email.
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $to      = "test@email.com";
            $subject = "Newsletter Sign Up";
            $message = "Email: {$_POST['email]}";
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. You have been signed up for our newsletter!</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This one is the only one that will not generate a warning that $error is not set if everything is correct. And we have to assume everything is correct most of the times so why generate a warning on each run of the page?

Comment: @Andreas It would only generate `$error` if `$_POST['submit']` is empty or not set. You shouldn't generate errors when there are no errors.

Comment: Ok that is true. I usually have a habit of removing any way for the php interpreter to create an error/warning.

Comment: @Andreas This shouldn't do that either as it checks if the variable exists before doing anything with it.

Comment: And that is what I meant. I upvoted this answer as it deals with any warnings/errors before they happen. The other answers do not, but it may be impossible to get to an error on them to, but I just like the fact that you made it completly impossible.

Comment: @Andreas Oh thank you, I misunderstood your first comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You're structure is wrong so it's always hitting that block.  You have the closing bracket for your if in the wrong place.  Try this.

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {
    if(!$_POST["email"]) {
        $error = 'Please Enter Your Email';     
    }
    if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in submitting the form: ' .$error. '</strong></div>';
    } else {
        if(mail("colin.vrugteman@hotmail.com", "Newsletter Sign Up", "Email: ".$_POST['email'])) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. You have been signed up for our newsletter!</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```